# Is there RDF that describes software defects?

Tags: bug-tracking, rdf, ontology

Background:

I know, via pypi, about [DOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_of_a_Project).  Is there something similar to describe software defects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toby has a [bug ontology](http://ontologi.es/doap-bugs#). It covers the sort of information you'd find in a bug tracker, and it thus more concerned with the process of handling defects rather than classifying the issue in depth.

In a similar vein tabulator is moving its issue list to [an rdf form](http://dig.csail.mit.edu/2010/issues/track#).

Comment: Linking it with DOAP makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this [Change Management specification](http://open-services.net/bin/view/Main/CmResourceDefinitionsV1) mentioned recently. Don't know exactly how it's being used, but appears to be intended for bug/issue tracking. The vocabulary itself is outlined here: http://open-services.net/bin/view/Main/CmSpecificationV2